# Can't read inbox from facebook in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to read information from facebook to determine wich are the friends that most interact with me. I give my app the following read permissions: "user_friends","user_groups", "user_interests", "read_mailbox" and "read_stream".

this the code i use to autenticate

```
authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends","user_groups", "user_interests", "read_mailbox","read_stream"));
```

When the login process is complete, i redirect to another activity where i try to read the data i need

```
Request inboxRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/inbox?limit=100", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(Response response) {
         if (response != null) {
         //My processing
         }
      }
});
```

When i run my app i get an error code in my response:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, 
errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token 
must be used to query information about the current user.}, isFromCache:false}
```

I debug my code and when i checked the session state it has an access token value, however it apears to be removed and i don't know why:

```
{Request:  session: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[installed, public_profile, read_stream, read_mailbox, user_interests, user_groups, user_friends]}, appId:xxxxx}, graphPath: me/inbox?limit=100, graphObject: null, restMethod: null, httpMethod: GET, parameters: Bundle[{access_token=xxxx, format=json, sdk=android}]}
```

I will be very grateful i someone help me with this issue, i can't get it working

(Sorry for my english)

Thanks